# Cant getJSON in my own PHP MVC

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

i'm trying to get database query results as json in MVC PHP to call ajax then . but it seems i cant get the json file .

**MODEL**

```
public function getAdsWithNoPermission(){
    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE admin_permission = 0");
    $rows = $this->db->getAllRows();
    return $rows;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(){
    session_start();
    $this->view('admin/index');
    print(json_encode($this->adminModel->getAdsWithNoPermission());
}
```

**JS SCRIPT IN VIEW ADMIN/INDEX**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    adsOutput();
})

function adsOutput(){
    $("#adsOutput").html("<p>Product list</p>");
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/findit/admins/index',function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

nothings happen in console just in html view i can see the data as json type that i thing is because of print function i wrote in controller.

Comment: It seems like has error in PHP but i am not sure. `$this->adminModel->getAdsWithNoPermission()` this one, does the controller `extends` or in one class with the model? And how come you call `adminModel` to a current class variable of  `$this` but not `adminModel()` as a method. I think it should be `$this->adminModel()->getAdsWithNoPermission()`.

Comment: the methods and models are correct and everything works if i want to go without ajax . the problem is how can i get the json in controller using getjson function in jquery . i tried to do that but it comes wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to just echo the JSON, I don't know what do have inside:

```
$this->view('admin/index');
```

Try it in a simple way like:

```
public function index(){
    session_start();
    echo(json_encode($this->adminModel->getAdsWithNoPermission());
}
```

And the request like:

```
   $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'http://localhost/findit/admins/index',
      data: [],
      success: function(response){console.log(response);}
    });
```

You shouldn't have HTML mixed with your JSON response. Hope I could help.